# how to create a hash table in java

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a csv file of 2 column. I`m trying to create a hash table for each dimension - only add a value if I haven't seen it before. I want to create 2 separate hash table for every column. columns contain string and numeric value. From the class definition i found containsKey(Object key) methoid Tests if the specified object is a key in this hashtable. i can explain a bit detail like my csv file may look like as below

```
New York, 50
Sydney, jessi
california, 10
New York, 10
```

so for column 1 New york came 2  in hash table i`d like to put key New York and value 2

can anyone help me how can i create a hash table like this way using java hashtable class, or maintain a separate array

Comment: Why does "New York" become "2"?

Comment: I suggest you actually read the documentation on `HashTable` (and classes it descends from).  This is not a code-generation site, you know.

Comment: How much data do you actually have? Do you really need a Hashtable? have you looked at using a simple Map?

Comment: I would recommend HashMap for a standard "go to" implementation, because being newer is cooler ;-) (Although HashTable has been retrofitted to Map.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) open source project on SourceForge called OpenCSV.

Then you could code something like this to read the CSV into your Map.

```
try {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/your/file.csv"))));
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(String[] row : reader.readAll()) {
        result.put(row[0], row[1]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can read more on the OpenCSV documentation [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: thanks a lot for your response , i'm reading hash map , i'm new of using hashtable and hashmap,...